# Beeline command issue

Tags: jdbc, hive, beeline

I am new to Hive and hopefully this is going to be an easy thing to solve
for someone with more experience, but I am having trouble doing it on my
own.

On my EC2 app server I am running the following command with no error:

***beeline -u jdbc:hive2://master***

This is working on Hive 13 which was installed through a bootstrap action
using the latest AMI version. 'master' is pointing to my EMR cluster

Then I downloaded the source for Hive 14 and built it. I have replaced my
/home/hadoop/hive directory with the package that was built.
However, if I try to execute the same command, I get an error:

```
scan complete in 6ms
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://master
Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://master:
Cannot open without port. (state=08S01,code=0)
Beeline version 0.14.0 by Apache Hive
0: jdbc:hive2://master (closed)>
```

Running it with the port provided works correctly:

**beeline -u jdbc:hive2://master:10000**

I would like to be able to able to run the command without providing the
default port number.
Can anyone direct me with an instruction.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Hive Beeline Connection in Two Modes:

**1.Embedded Mode:**

If both Hive Client and Hive server are same then connect beeline by using below url:

```
     !connect jdbc:hive2://
```

2.Remote Mode:

If server in one machine but client in one machine you can connect beeline using below url:

```
!connect jdbc:hive2://<host>:<port>
```